# Django told me connection already closed

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I am using Django and I am trying to do a request :

```
myobject = Myobject.objects.get(myid=myid)[0]
mycolor = myobject.color
```

But Django told me that : psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

I don't understand why I cannot get mycolor...

Do you have any ideas to solve this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `qs.get()` returns a single object, so the slice at the end seems wrong, although most probably unrelated to your error.

Comment: Make sure your database config is correct